# Edit Hidden Item in List

Tags: 2007, list, list-item, hidden

I'm using SharePoint 2007 and I'm trying to figure out a way to hide a group of fields from being options in a new-item form when a list item is being created by an end-user. However, I also want to make those hidden items available to be edited by an administrator at a later time. Let me be a bit more specific:

1. I have a list of items, some of which are required/optional and some of which are hidden.
2. I want a visitor to my site to be able to make a new item by filling in a form where only the required/optional fields are visible.
3. I then, as an administrator with full control, want to be able to go back after this item is uploaded and add values to the other hidden fields.

I am open to hearing out other methods of doing this if anyone has suggestions. Unforunately, implementing anything through code isn't an option as my employer has standard SharePoint templates so I'm not allowed to implement anything through code that isn't available from the GUI interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view with the hidden columns in it and then use the Datasheet view to make changes.

You can create a custom EditForm page to show the fields.

You could make the fields optional and use javascript/jQuery hidden in a content editor web part on the NewForm page to hide the fields.

Comment: Hello, I've actually already tried the first route and it seems that the Datasheet view is read-only even though the Item list content type is NOT set to read only. Could you expand on how to implement the second and/or third options please?

Comment: Or, alternatively, could you explain how to make it so that the Datasheet view isn't read only? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depending on the fields in your view, the datasheet may become read only. Try creating a datasheet view with only the minimal fields needed to identify and update the data. I'll expand the other options.

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow when I get into the office. In the meantime, thanks for your help so far. I'd vote up your answer but I don't yet have upvote privileges on SharePoint stack exchange.

Comment: I tried your suggestion of changing the view to be only those fields that needed to be filled in and it didn't work :-/ When you get a chance would you mind expanding the second and third options you'd mentioned before?